# From Windows Vista to 7, can I get rid of folder Windows.old?

Tags: windows-7, formatting, installation, hard-drive

I've just changed my laptop OS from Windows Vista to Windows 7.

I didn't choose to have both OS together, I just want to have Windows 7.

I was specting Windows 7 instalation program to format/clean my HD and leave me most of its capacity for a fresh start. But I've found, once the OS has been isntalled, that all files and programs from the Vista era are still in my HD, in a folder called Windows.old

I don't need these programs and files, I want to have as much HD space as possible and Windows 7 as clean as possible, what should I do? 
Can I just delete Windows.old folder? Would that affect the how Windows 7 works?

Maybe is because I ended up angry with Vista, but I don't like the fact that there wasn't any cleaning/formatting ..

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/How-do-I-remove-the-Windows-old-folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows.old basically just contains your old copy of Windows. You'll be able to copy your old documents from the folder and then delete it. You can manually delete the folder although if you run [Disk Cleanup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/8fef4121-711b-4be1-996f-99e02c7301c2/disk-cleanup-in-windows-10) it will delete the folder automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The windows.old folder gives you a second chance at getting back useful files that initialy escaped your mind before the reinstallation of windows. If u dn't need it,best thing is to shred the entire folder. You may download austogics and use the shredder in it.  I hope this helps.